# CouchDB backlog performance

Tags: lucene, couchdb

I am working on a web service that uses CouchDB as its primary database.  The setup runs as follows:

1. A small main database for high-level business logic
2. Large client databases (~5GB ea.) containing homogeneous records
3. Couchdb-Lucene indexing these large client databases

With out application, we receive approx. 2-20 posts per second from clients (only about 10 clients), containing records to be inserted into their database.  Each post handler contains logic that needs to look up client details from the main database.  We're experiencing an issue where CouchDB GETs and POSTs are taking upwards of 180s to complete.  CouchDB processes are dominating the CPU, so I expect that this is a problem where CouchDB can't keep up with its indexing.

Any idea on how to optimize performance in a situation like this where we have a steady stream of records that need to be indexed ASAP?

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that this amount of data is enough to overwhelm CouchDB, but it's impossible to say without digging into the actual code of your post handlers and view functions. You might want to profile these in more detail to see where the bottlenecks are (or hire a consultant to help with this).

Comment: I've done my best to gather some metrics, but the _stats endpoint seems to offer up very little.  Are there any other techniques you know of to for this kind of profiling?